# From Windows Server 2012 to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, troubleshooting, formatting, windows-server-2012

Hi I formatted my laptop a month ago to test windows server 2012, now I want to format it again to back to its previous OS which is windows 8. I used a bootable flash drive(IMATION 8gb) containing the windows 8 OS and I set the first boot priority to the Flash Drive. But then the computer does not read the drive and continue in booting windows server 2012. What should I do?

My Laptop is Samsung NP535U4CL 
AMD A8-4555M 1.60 GHz
4gb RAM
64 bit

Answer (score 1):

If your boot order is set correctly but USB is still not booting, it can only mean that your USB install media was not prepared correctly.

I would suggest using either [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) or [Windows 7 USB/DVD tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to "burn" iso to USB.

Comment: Backing the Windows USB/DVD tool.

Comment: Actually I tried to boot it in other computer and it work. But when in my laptop with Windows Server 2012 OS not working. I don't know why.

Comment: I used Novicorp WinToFlash for creating a bootable flash drive

Comment: if it works on other computer then you ruled out that flash is bad. It means that your BIOS settings are not set correctly to boot from USB. p.s. Don't use USB3 ports to boot via USB.

Comment: But I already set the first boot priority to my flashdrive, And I don't know why my laptop does'nt read it. I try different usb port of my laptop but still not working.

Comment: Well as a last resort I would still try different USB. Maybe for some reason your laptop can't boot off that one?

Comment: But this what I used too in formatting it in windows server, Anyway I will try another flash drive or a CD if still not work.